# How to click ok on a msgbox on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i have this code

but When I want to open 1.xls, I encounter an error that I should click on ok to close the error and open the excel file.
Because this code will download Excel files from the Internet, downloaded files will have this problem

I'm looking for a way to not see this error, or the app automatically clicks on ok.

```
Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Envid\Desktop\1.xls")
Set wkb2 = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets("sheet name")
Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets(wsname)

sht1.Cells.copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

wkb1.Close True

Kill ("C:\Users\Envid\Desktop\1.xls")    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply prevent alerts from displaying, you can use the following

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

But once you have gotten past the lines that you are trying to ingore alerts, set it back to True so you can catch any unintended alerts.

I assume it's the `wkb1.Close` line where you're trying to avoid an alert, so modify it as follows:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wkb1.Close True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: it's true.
thank you
I used the "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" code before i open excel file and Excel files open without any error or It is better to say that errors have disappeared